# Probability one blood test out of 20 tests with 95% accuracy is wrong

Tags: probability

I recently underwent a blood test that measured 20 different things. Each of these 20 measurements was 95% accurate. What is the chance that one of the results I received is inaccurate?

I had a discussion about this over Christmas with my family. These were the three answers:

1. 5%
2. Much lower than 5%
3. $100 - (19/20)^{20} \times 100\%$

who was right?

To clarify: I want to know what the odds are that exactly one test among 20 tests is inaccurate.

Comment: Exactly one result, at least one result, no more than one result, "is inaccurate "?

Comment: What do you mean by the measurement being $95$% 'accurate?Typically, the 'accuracy' of a test is understood in terms of true or false positives or negatives. So, for example, where $D$ is the event of having the disease, and $T$ the event of the test being positive (i.e. suiggesting I have the disease), then we could have that $P(T|D)=0.95$. Is that how we are to interpret this?

Comment: I wondered what the odds are that exactly one is inaccurate.

Comment: Exactly one is a binomial, with $N=20$, $p=0.95$ and $k=19$

Comment: Bas, I edited your comment below your question to include it within your post.

Comment: Note also that the Probability of x happening is not the same thing as the odds of x happening.

Answer (score 1):

All three possibilities are correct, depending on how you phrase the question. The first is correct if you mean "what is the probability that one *given, specific* vial is inaccurate". The third option is correct if you mean "what is the probability that *at least* one vial is innaccurate". The second is wrong.

The first case is obvious.

For the third option, we can see that it is the same as the probability that not every vial was accurately tested. So, the probability is 100 - (the probability that every vial was accurately tested) %. The probability that every vial is accurately tested is, of course, $(19/20)^{20}$, so the probability in this case is $1 - (19/20)^{20}$, which is approximately 64.2%.

Alternatively, the probability that *exactly* one vial is also worth investigating. The probability that our first vial was incorrect is $1/20$, and the probability that our following $19$ were accurate is $(19/20)^{19}$. So, the probability that *only* our *first* vial is innaccurate is $(1/20)(19/20)^{19}$. Of course, there's 20 different options for *which* vial is innaccurate, which brings the probability of *exactly* one vial being innaccurate to $(19/20)^{19}$ which is approximately 37.7%.

Comment: @amWhy Pardon me, thank you for the correction. I've rewritten the answer to point out that it doesn't lead to any of the possible answers given by the OP, but is still worth considering.

Comment: Happy to help.  I just recognized your work as correct, save for the final presentation.  I upvoted your answer earlier because you gave the various possibilities of interpretation, and clearly thought about it!

Answer (score 1):

I picked up the comment of MatMorPau22 and highvoted it.

The point is, that exactly one result is inaccurate is the same as exactly 19 tests are accurate. Now we must assume, that all test and results are independent. The random variable $X$ counts the number of accurate results. Then the distribution of $X$ is a binomial with $n=20$ and $p=0.95$, thus the answer to the question is simply
$$P(X=19)=\binom{20}{19}0.95^{19}\cdot 0.05\approx 37.73\%$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the things measured are independent, the chance of getting everything right is $$\frac{95}{100}\cdot\frac{95}{100}\cdot\frac{95}{100}\cdot...\frac{95}{100}=(\frac{95}{100})^{20}$$ So, the chance of one or more inaccurate result(s) is $1-\left(\frac{95}{100}\right)^{20} \approx 64\%$

Comment: is there a way to find out what the odds are for each possibility? (one inaccurate result, two inaccurate, three inaccurate.... results)

Comment: That's not the probability that exactly one result was inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can (also) use the binomial probability distribution here (altough the most intuitive result would be `1-0.95^20`). But just to provide an additional solution:

```
p=0.95
q=0.05
n=20
```

$$
 \binom{20}{0} 0.95^{20}  0.05^{0} = 0.358
$$
we get ~36% that ALL of them are correct, hence you get `1-0.358 = 0.64%` that at least one is incorrect.

Looking again at your question I see you're asking for **exactly one error (any of the 20)** it should be:

$$
 \binom{20}{19} 0.95^{19}  0.05^{1} = 0.377
$$

Comment: The question is, what the probability for exactly one inaccurate test is

Comment: @Fakemistake thanks for pointing this out! I over read :-)